# Kusto query cancelled due to appended alias statements

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I wrote a Kusto query which runs in under 1 minute however the same query gets cancelled for a colleague due to a 10x longer runtime. I collected some metadata about both query runs using .show queries and found that he had the same ClientRequestProperties with even less cache misses however there were 400+ alias database statements appended to the start of his query text. Is there some connection or user settings that could be causing these alias statements to be appended?

Answer (score 1):

The alias statements themselves (400+) should not have a negative impact, however, it can be that these statements point to other clusters, in that case, the query may turn to be a query that is sent to many clusters and is not the same as the first query.

The next steps should be to ensure that the semantics of the two queries that you compare are identical, if they are, then please open a support ticket so that the team can investigate.

If you need help evaluating the semantics of the queries, please edit your question and provide a sample, simplified, and anonymized query that will allow better analysis of the issue.